# How do i convert a list of strings into a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, split

I'd like to convert a list of structurally similar strings into a list of dictionaries.

Example list of strings:

```
list_of_strings = [
'ID payment_method email issue_date payment_date amount currency',
'ID payment_method email issue_date payment_date amount currency',
'ID payment_method email issue_date payment_date amount currency',
...
]
```

Each snippet of information is sperated by a whitespace inside the strings themselves.

Desired output:

```
resulting_list_of_dicts = [
dict_1 = {"ID": "id1", "payment_method": "paymentmethod1", "e_mail": "email1", "payment_date": "paymentdate1", "amount": "amount1", "currency": "currecny1"},
dict_2 = {"ID": "id2", "payment_method": "paymentmethod2", "e_mail": "email1", "payment_date": "paymentdate2", "amount": "amount2", "currency": "currecny2"},
...
]
```

I've tried using the string split function, by I am running into trouble when trying to append the sub strings to a dict.

Comment: Please include your code and explain what problems you're running into.

Comment: You can use the code to convert one string to one dictionary and then repeat this for all strings in the list.

Comment: You can't put an assignment inside a list. What are `list_1`, `list_2`, etc. supposed to be?

Comment: What trouble are you running into? It should be as simple as `{"ID": substring[0], "payment_method": substring[1], ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over each line in the string list.

Use `split()` to get each separate part.

Build a new dictionary from those parts and append it to another list.

```
list_of_dicts = [] 
for s in list_of_strings:
    parts = s.split()
    list_of_dicts.append({
        'id': parts[0],
        'payment_method': parts[1],
        ... and so on
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, i was struggling with the other provided solutions, because i actually don't want to contain all the information of the initial strings in the new list of dicts. Some of the people who answered seemd to have missed that part.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of all the keys you want in the dictionary. Then you can combine this with the split string to make each dictionary, using the technique in [Make a dictionary (dict) from separate lists of keys and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/make-a-dictionary-dict-from-separate-lists-of-keys-and-values)

```
keys = ['ID', 'payment_method', 'email', 'issue_date', 'payment_date', 'amount', 'currency']
resulting_list_of_dicts = [dict(zip(keys, item.split())) for item in list_of_strings]
```